# Getting notified when a BLE device is turned on

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a bluetooth low energy device that I want to get notified once it is on and starts broadcasting.
Is there a way to use a broadcast receiver in android to get notified the device was turned on without entering the app?

Thank you

Comment: I use the AltBeacon library from RadiusNetwork: https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/notifications.html

Comment: It is possible to implement this algorithm in the scanning functionality, but you must do it in an application. It is not possible to change the default manufacture settings of your Smartphone.